# Iterating Loops in ModelBuilder of ArcMap 10.6.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I am trying to iterate through rows of a table, amass a list of distance values and then use those values as the Distance parameter in the Multiple Ring Buffer tool.

All of this works great, except 1 important detail: IT WON'T STOP LOOPING.

It goes through the tools fine. Generates the buffer output. Then starts looping again. I did each step by manually and it doesn't cause a problem. It is just that Iterate Row Selection will start the model over.

I looked into the properties of Iterate Feature Selection and model itself. The only thing I could find about controlling the interations was the tab below, but it is all grayed out.

**Edited**: I got the model to a point where it doesn't return errors. However, it iterates collecting the distance values. On the first iteration, it creates the buffer for -0.5. Then it starts the iteration over and overwrites the buffer feature class with a buffer for -0.5 and -0.65. Then it starts over and collects the values for -0.5, -0.65 and -0.84.  Then overwrites the buffer feature class with this new buffer feature class. And so on and so forth. Each time the CollectValues parameter increases by one. I want it to collect all of the values then put them into the Multiple Buffer tool. I am not sure why it  starts the iteration over. My model follows the examples ESRI gives for the tool.

```
Data:
 Distance
-0.50000
-0.65000
-0.84500
-1.09850
-1.42805
-1.85647
-2.41340
-3.13743
-4.07865
-5.30225
-6.89292
-8.96080
-11.64904
-15.14376
-19.68688
```

[image]
 [image: 10]

Comment: Feel free to edit your question to include additional information such as screenprints of the model.  Possible useful video tutorial for this iterator in model builder: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDlfwZVNz_g

Comment: Do you have anything in the group by fields? Are you wanting to loop through each individual feature (one at a time) or a set of features?

Comment: Are you using iterate feature selection (feature classes) or iterate row selection (tables)?

Comment: It sounds like something like using Lists in model builder would work with the multiple ring buffer - have you looked at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/using-lists.htm?

Comment: @smiller I noticed when I take out the Iterate Row Selection part of the model, the parameters light up and I can select the parameters to be set to 1. When I bring in the Iterate Row Selection tool it toggles to the screenshot I added above and grays out.

Comment: edited to attach my model.

Comment: I am trying to go row by row in the field. They are all calculated to be unique. I collect them with "Collect Values" and then feed them into the Distance parameter of the Multiple Ring Buffers tools.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the data?

Comment: Edited to add the data

Comment: Put the iterator and collects tool in it's own model, this becomes a sub model. So then you have a main model with your excel to table tool connecting to a sub-model which feeds out a LIST of values that go into the buffer tool. Your current configuration is highly inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Hornbydd mentioned in the a comment to my original post, submodels are the way to go. Once I understood exactly how to nest submodel, it worked like a charm. I am not sure how I didn't learn this before...

Anyway, a step by step workaround on how to fix this with submodels can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpKXve4NxqU

This is not my video, but was very informative on how to nest submodels.